# Implementing LMS

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

I already created my own version of the hash based signature scheme LMS, but my signing results do not match the test vectors provided in the RFC. I am not sure what I do wrong, thus I wanted to try to run the reference implementation from cisco, although it is way more complicated, a little bit too complicated for me.

I wanted to split my test vectors into creating the right LMOTS private and public keys, creating the right signature and then creating the LMS public key + auth_path. When I run the reference implementation code demo.c it should produce me the private key, although it only refunds me the used SEED and I.

How can I use the reference implementation code to generate LMOTS private and public keys with outputs, so I could compare them with my own vectors and see where I am mistaken? Could you guide me a little on how to use the functions from the reference implementation?

I tried using the lmots_generate_signature function to somehow retrieve the private key during the process, although the seed value is not a simple char array of the SEED from test vectors and I dont know what I should insert there.

Comment: For this level of detail about a specific implementation, you might be better off emailing the author of the tool.  In this case, the guy's a jerk, but he may be willing to support what he wrote...